# ¿Cómo obtener un archivo .xlsx desde un servidor y luego transformarlo a JSON?

Tags: nodejs, excel

Intente esto con la libreria convert-excel-to-json pero no me dio resultado.

```
const {data} = await axios.get(url, { responseType:"arraybuffer" })
console.log(data);
const result = await excelToJson({
source: fs.readFileSync(data)
})
console.log(result);

Si saben como resolverlo, sea con esta libreria u otra, lo agradeceria mucho.
```

Comment: Quizás te sea de utilidad: https://codebeautify.org/excel-to-json Saludos.